Abbreviate Wordpress post view numbers
Can anyone please walk me through how to make post views on Wordpress shorten to 10K or 1.1M rather than displaying the full number 10,000 or 1,000,000.
I found the code below but not sure how to implement it into the Wordpress child theme. Putting it into the functions.php file didn't do anything.
    /**
 * Shorten long numbers to K/M/B (Thousand, Million and Billion)
 *
 * @param int $number The number to shorten.
 * @param int $decimals Precision of the number of decimal places.
 * @param string $suffix A string displays as the number suffix.
 */
if(!function_exists('short_number')) {
function short_number($n, $decimals = 2, $suffix = '') {
    if(!$suffix)
        $suffix = 'K,M,B';
    $suffix = explode(',', $suffix);

    if ($n < 1000) { // any number less than a Thousand
        $shorted = number_format($n);
    } elseif ($n < 1000000) { // any number less than a million
        $shorted = number_format($n/1000, $decimals).$suffix[0];
    } elseif ($n < 1000000000) { // any number less than a billion
        $shorted = number_format($n/1000000, $decimals).$suffix[1];
    } else { // at least a billion
        $shorted = number_format($n/1000000000, $decimals).$suffix[2];
    }

    return $shorted;
}
}


Can you find the code that's showing the post views? What are you using to count them - Jetpack, your theme / child theme, some other plugin? I don't think WordPress does this itself out of the box.

I am using a plugin called 'Post Views For Jetpack'. The author of that plugin advised this... "The plugin relies on WordPress' own number_format_i18n function to display the numbers. That function includes its own filter ( https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/number_format_i18n/ ) that you could use to customize the display of the numbers to fit your needs, by hooking into the filter from your own code in a custom snippet."

Your function as presented in the question isn't hooked to anything. Add add_filter( 'number_format_i18n', 'short_number', 10, 3); to your functions.php file and see if that does what you want it to.
